# Is it true that $ \int_0^\infty 2^{-x}\,dx=\sum_{x=0}^{\infty}\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{2^{-x}}{k}$?

Tags: calculus

Is it true that $$ \int_0^{\infty} 2^{-x}\,dx=\sum_{x=0}^{\infty}\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{2^{-x}}{k}\,\,?$$

Here is my try:

\begin{align}
&  \sum_{x=0}^{\infty}\lim_{k\to\infty}\dfrac{2^{-x}}{k}\\
&= \lim_{k\to\infty}\sum_{x=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{2^{-x}}{k} \\
&= \lim_{h\to0+}\sum_{x=0}^{\infty}2^{-x}h \\
&= \int_0^{\infty} 2^{-x}\,dx \\
&= \frac{1}{\log{2}}
\end{align}

Is it correct? I have doubts because doing

\begin{align}
&  \sum_{x=0}^{\infty}\lim_{k\to\infty}\dfrac{2^{-x}}{k}\\
&= \lim_{k\to\infty}\dfrac 1k\sum_{x=0}^{\infty}2^{-x} \\
&= \lim_{k\to\infty}\dfrac 2k \\
&= 0 \neq \frac 1{\log 2}
\end{align}

I get another answer from the same equation.

Comment: no,RHS is equal to zero

Comment: What is $\sum_{x=0}^\infty $

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fallacy is in assuming $\int_0^\infty f(x) dx=\lim_{h\to 0^+}\sum_{n=0}^\infty hf(n)$; the right-hand side should be $\lim_{h\to 0^+}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{h}{2}(f(hn)+f(hn+h))$. You can convince yourself of this by drawing thin trapezia under a curve.